Is it possible to produce to a Kafka server using something like postman
I am interested in trying to produce a message onto an existing Kafka topic using a framework for generic REST requests. What I am thinking is if I can produce a message using a tool like postman then I can take the postman configuration and adapt it for my existing framework.
I have been reviewing many sources related to Kafka documentation and it definitely seems like this should be possible but none of the documentation I have found is straightforward enough to inform what the postman request should look like.
For clarity here is the setup. The Kafka is running with three bootstrap servers and I have the three servernames. I know which topic I should be posting to. The security protocol is set up to be SASL_PLAINTEXT and the SASL Mechanism is SCRAM_SHA_512. For authentication I have a username and a password.
Any information anyone has either 1. confirming if this is even possible and 2. sourcing appropriate documentation would be enormously helpful.
I attempted configuring a postman request using the details I have provided but I am consistently getting a connection refused. The primary configuration parameters I am unsure how to properly implement are how to make a post when there are three bootstrap servers and where/how the security protocol and SASL mechanisms should be configured if at all possible.

Postman is an HTTP Client, so in order to "produce to Kafka", you'd need a Kafka REST Proxy that exposes an HTTP server in front of Kafka's own TCP server interface.
That proxy is where the SASL/SSL details for Kafka would be configured, then you would have the option of additional HTTP authorization on top of that.
